# Beginner needs Help! Countdown timer not working JS

Tags: javascript, html, countdowntimer

I just started learning how to make websites with HTML, and I needed to create a timer. The timer is displaying but the numbers are not and it is not working.

I would appreciate your help guys :)
Below is the HTML and CSS

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var countDownDate = new Date("July 21, 2021 09:00:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function(){
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;


  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distancr % (1000 * 60)) / (1000));

    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = days;
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hours;
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = seconds;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Define “not working." Also note that this can be created as a runnable snippet on SO, making behavior testing even easier for those trying to help.

Comment: `distancr` is misspelled when you declare `var seconds…`

Comment: I've answered your question, but as @DaveNewton says, you must make a bigger effort on how you ask your questions

Answer (score 1):

`window.setInterval` takes a second argument, after the function to be executed, and that's the number of miliseconds between each execution.
Also, as Kirk Beard pointed out in a comment, you misspelled `distance` on the line attributing the `seconds` variable

So:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var countDownDate = new Date("July 21, 2021 09:00:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function(){
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;


  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / (1000));

    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = days;
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hours;
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = seconds;
}, 1000); // 1000 ms = 1 second
</script>
```

I haven't checked the rest of the code, looking for other possible bugs, but i figure this is the solution to your problem